# How can I make an iPhone OS 2.1 project with the new Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Problem: I want to make iPhone OS 2.1 apps, but Xcode now always makes automatically an iPhone OS 3.0 project. I forgot about it and now I have an app which I want to test on my iPod touch, but I need to build OS 2.1. Is there a way to get this working?

The dropdown from top left in Xcode only offers to build for OS 3.0 device. However, when I open old projects, there I have OS 2.1 available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project > Edit Project Settings.

Then select the General tab (although it should be selected by default.

Select the SDK you want at 'Base SDK for all configurations'.

Should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new SDK and still build for an older OS.
Go to Target ---> Deployment and then set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 3.0. (or whatever value you'd like)